# Why img.draw(canvas) not showing any image?

Tags: android, imageview

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.gridlines);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 200, 200, true);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
            img.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            img.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            img.draw(canvas);

        //setContentView(img);


}
```

I am new to android above code grid lines is image it is in resource drawable folder i create a bitmap and set the bitmap to canvas ,now canvas holding bitmap which i created as per canvas construction..then i have created an image view then called image.draw(canvas)...then image not showing in canvas...actually image view holding ic_lancher image. that image should draw into the canvas but it is not drawn for me .